# Webpack unable to find some module

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs

I've installed webpack in my requirejs project to bundle the dependencies and page specific js into 1 file. However, at the moment it is able to just bundle jquery, bootstrap and custom js. Other dependencies like handlebars, bootstrap-selectpicker are not being found by webpack

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   entry: './src/app/page/report/report.js',
   output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
       filename: 'bundle.js'
   }
 };
```

report.js

```
const $ = require("jquery");
const bootstrap = require("bootstrap");
const Handlebars= require("handlebars"); // this line gives error - Module not found

$(document).on('click', function(){
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

require_config.js

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: cbp.staticBasePath,

urlArgs: "buildDate=" + buildDate,

//Since Bootstrap is not an AMD module, shim it
shim: {
    "bootstrap": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "jQuery.fn.popover"
    },
    "bootstrap-select": {
        deps: ["bootstrap"],
        exports: "bootstrap-select"
    },
    "bootstrap-table": {
        deps: ["jquery", "bootstrap"],
        exports: "bootstrapTable"
    },
},
paths: {

    // Vendor libraries paths
    "jquery-ui": "assets/js/min/jquery-ui.min",
    "modernizr": "assets/js/min/modernizr.min",
    "jquery": "assets/js/min/jquery.min",
    "bootstrap": "assets/js/min/bootstrap.min",
    "handlebars": "assets/js/min/handlebars.min",

    // Components JS file paths
    "bootstrap-table": "app/components/table/bootstrap-table.min",
    "bootstrap-select": "app/components/dropdown/bootstrap-select.min",
}

});
```

Following is my project folder structure :-

```
my-proj
build
src
    app
        components
            selectpicker
                selectpicker.hbs
                selectpicker.js
                selectpicker.less
            calendar
                calendar.hbs
                calendar.js
                calendar.less
            ...
            ...
            ...
        page
            homepage
                homepage.html
                homepage.js
            report
                report.html
                report.js
            ...
            ...
            ...
    assets
        images
        js
            jquery.js
            modernizr.js
            handlebar.js
            require.js
            bootstrap.js
            moment.js
            ...
            ...
            ...
        less
Gruntfile.js
package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack knows nothing about your `require.js` config. To resolve modules it searches `node_modules` directory by default.

1. You probably should define `resolve` section in your webpack config(assume that webpack config is in `src` folder):

   ```
   module.exports = {
   //...
      resolve: {
         alias: {
             // Vendor libraries paths
             "jquery-ui": "./assets/js/min/jquery-ui.min",
             "modernizr": "./assets/js/min/modernizr.min",
             "jquery": "./assets/js/min/jquery.min",
             "bootstrap": "./assets/js/min/bootstrap.min",
             "handlebars": "./assets/js/min/handlebars.min",

              // Components JS file paths
             "bootstrap-table": "./app/components/table/bootstrap-table.min",
             "bootstrap-select": "./app/components/dropdown/bootstrap-select.min",
         }
      }
   };
   ```
2. or if you don't want these annoying duplicates, try to add (but I think this way you should have slightly different path to modules to make it works, example: `./assets/js/min/bootstrap/bootstrap.js`):

   ```
   //...
   resolve: {
       modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/js/min')]
   }
   ```

**P.S.** Sorry, I don't know all your project architecture, but common solution for bundling `requirejs`(and `systemjs`) projects is to bundle it with gulp or grunt builders that creates special bundle for `requirejs` which just provides case that all AMD modules are already loaded. I think webpack will create bundle that will not work with requirejs as expected.

Comment: You are correct that bundling for requirejs should be done with gulp or grunt. Require has a optimization tool r.js - http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html that does that. The problem I have is that I'll have to change my project folder structure if I have to use r.js. I want to avoid that.